# Access SQL Query / Expression to Compare Two Records in Same Table for SCRUM

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've been banging my head against the wall on this one for days. I feel like this should be simple, but I keep finding loop holes in all the queries I create.

### Example Data

Long story short, through a series of queries, I have generated a data set similar to the example below:

```
RequestID     Status
45            Completed
87            Completed
87            Acknowledged
87            In Progress
87            Blocked
99            New
```

### Example Results

The next step for me is running a query on this data set so only ONE SCRUM `Status` remains for each `RequestID` based on the following parameters. Thus for the example above, I would want my result to show:

```
RequestID     Status
45            Completed
87            Blocked
99            New
```

### Logic Tree

Here is my UML logic tree that I can't seem to figure out how to translate into Access (***please note:*** I'm just showing the entire logic tree for future readers. For my troubleshooting, Case 1, 2, 4 are the only unique logic expressions that I need help translating into an Access SQL query)...

*All cases below are based on a per `RequestID` basis.*

1. IF any record of a specific `RequestID` has a `Status` ="Blocked"; resulting `Status` is ="Blocked".
2. IF any record of a specific `RequestID` has a `Status` ="Awaiting Approval" AND no records for that specific `RequestID` has a `Status` is ="Blocked"; resulting `Status` is ="Awaiting Approval".
3. IF any record of a specific `RequestID` has a `Status` ="In Progress" AND no records for that specific `RequestID` has a `Status` is ="Blocked" AND no records for that specific `RequestID` has a `Status` is ="Awaiting Approval"; resulting `Status` is ="In Progress".
4. IF any record of a specific `RequestID` has a `Status` ="Completed" AND there ARE records for that specific `RequestID` has a `Status` is ="Acknowledged"... AND no records for that specific `RequestID` has a `Status` is ="Blocked" AND no records for that specific `RequestID` has a `Status` is ="Awaiting Approval"; resulting `Status` is ="In Progress".
5. IF any record of a specific `RequestID` has a `Status` ="Acknowledged" AND no records for that specific `RequestID` has a `Status` is ="Blocked" AND no records for that specific `RequestID` has a `Status` is ="Awaiting Approval" AND no records for that specific `RequestID` has a `Status` is ="Completed" AND no records for that specific `RequestID` has a `Status` is ="In Progress"; resulting `Status` is ="Acknowledged".
6. IF any record of a specific `RequestID` has a `Status` ="New" AND no records for that specific `RequestID` has a `Status` is ="Blocked" AND no records for that specific `RequestID` has a `Status` is ="Awaiting Approval" AND no records for that specific `RequestID` has a `Status` is ="Completed" AND no records for that specific `RequestID` has a `Status` is ="In Progress" AND no records for that specific `RequestID` has a `Status` is ="Acknowledged"; resulting `Status` is ="New".

### Troubleshooting

Since I'm comparing multiple rows in the table maybe it requires a `self-join`? Or maybe it can be done with an IIF statement for the resulting `Status` field? I don't know. Every attempt I make seems to fail, so at this point I'd really love someone's insight regarding how I can do this in Access!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is a pure SQL solution required? Or, would the use of a VBA function within the SQL be permissible?

Comment: in step 4, what is the status for Completed but not Acknowledged? (assuming no other rules come into play.)

Comment: @MJH - Yes, VBA would be fine if you can help me figure something out!

Comment: @DonGeorge - Great question. In logic 4, take this example: if I have 3 tasks for a 'RequestID', one is "Complete", but the remaining two are still in "Acknowledged", then the overall task is not "Complete" NOR "Acknowledge"... instead, it is now "In Progress". (i.e. - only 33% complete so it's not complete, but as a result, it is also not just 'acknowledged because some of it has been worked thus 'in progress')

Comment: I'll take a look at it. Although, it would help if you could provide more extensive datasets for both the "Example Data" and "Example Results". Currently, there doesn't appear to be sufficient data to test some of your "Logic Tree" cases (e.g. #2 through #5).

Comment: @MJH - Hey, just wanted to give you a heads up that I marked this is answered. Don George gave a fairly straight forward SQL statement that with just a minor amount of tweaking I was able to get working perfectly! Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I'm glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT RequestID, 
Min(IIf([status]="Blocked",Yes)) AS B, 
Min(IIf([status]="Awaiting approval",Yes)) AS W, 
Min(IIf([status]="In Progress",Yes)) AS IP, 
Min(IIf([status]="Completed",Yes)) AS C, 
Min(IIf([status]="acknowledged",Yes)) AS Ack, 
Min(IIf([status]="New",Yes)) AS N, 
Switch([B],"Blocked",[W],"Awaiting Aproval",[IP],"In Progress",[C] And [Ack],"In Progress",[Ack],"Acknowledged",[N],"New") AS Result
FROM Status
GROUP BY RequestID;
```

This doesn't deal with the question above - it leaves the result blank for Completed but not Acknowledged as blank - but you should be able to modify the logic once you get the rules defined better.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I assumed a switch case might work (lol thus why I was calling these cases in my "please note" comment), but I couldn't figure it out! Let me tinker with your code quick and if I can get something working I'll mark your response as the answer. Thanks again!